# Connecting Terraform remote backend with Gitlab fails

Tags: terraform, gitlab, synchronization, gitlab-ci, terraform-state

I’m new to terraform. I’m not able to connect to the Gitlab remote Terraform managed backend. The state file is out of sync.

To be clear, nothing throws error, everything seems to work fine. But I know that on my local machine the terraform state file is out of sync from the Gitlab one because when the gitlab ci finishes I have one instance launched, but when I do `terraform plan` on my local machine, the plan says it will create an instance. It should not because there is already an instance running on the infrastructure.

Here is my `provider.tf` file:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.14.0" # Takes into account Terraform versions from 0.14.0
  required_providers {
    openstack = {
      source  = "terraform-provider-openstack/openstack"
      version = "~> 1.42.0"
    }

    ovh = {
      source  = "ovh/ovh"
      version = ">= 0.13.0"
    }
  }
  backend "http" {
    address        = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXX/terraform/state/$TF_STATE_NAME"
    lock_address   = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXX/terraform/state/$TF_STATE_NAME/lock"
    unlock_address = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXX/terraform/state/$TF_STATE_NAME/lock"
  }
}

# Configure the OpenStack provider hosted by OVHcloud
provider "openstack" {
  auth_url    = "https://auth.cloud.ovh.net/v3/" # Authentication URL
  domain_name = "default"                        # Domain name - Always at 'default' for OVHcloud
  alias       = "ovh"                            # An alias
}

provider "ovh" {
  region             = "BHS5"
  alias              = "ovh"
  endpoint           = "ovh-eu"
  application_key    = OVH_APPLICATION_KEY
  application_secret = OVH_APPLICATION_SECRET
  consumer_key       = OVH_CONSUMER_KEY
}
```

And I have run the `terraform init` command that I copied from gitlab under `operate` → `Terraform states` → `Actions` → `Copy Terraform init command`, and everything worked fine, no errors.

What am I missing?